# Can WebSocket addresses carry parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

Is `ws://myserver.com/path?param=1` a valid WebSocket address ?

The address `http://myserver.com/path?param=1` (notice it's now `http` and not `ws`) works fine with [`wscat`](https://github.com/einaros/ws#wscat-against-echowebsocketorg), but I can't get it working on the browser.

Comment: the url can be whatever.

Comment: Why are you trying at access a WebSocket address with an `http:` scheme?

Comment: @apsillers I wasn't, and I was surprised wscat allowed me to..

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Is it to establish a WS connection with a predefined parameter? Another solution is to include that parameter in the initial message the client sends to the server.

Comment: How would one include a parameter in the initial message?

Comment: @apsillers Using params may allow to pre-parse an auth token. As I understand, it's quite expensive to establish a websocket, so we could pre-parse the query param from the URL and either authenticate the client or just disconnect. Not sure if it's the same in JS, but I am doing exactly this in Java/socket.io. It may require patching the library, but checking auth in the first message opens you up to DDOS attacks (due to the cost of establishing a wss).

Comment: I had an issue with my parameter because the value contained a '#', which is of course not allowed because it is part of URI syntax. Make sure you escape your parameter values with `encodeURIComponent`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`ws://myserver.com/path?param=1` is a valid WebSocket URI. However, the way that your WebSocket server application can access the path and query string will differ depending on what WebSocket server framework you are using.

If you are using the Node.js [`einaros/ws`](https://github.com/websockets/ws/) library, then in your websocket connection object will have the full path with the query string at `upgradeReq.url`.

For example this:

```
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    console.log("url: ", ws.upgradeReq.url);
};
```

will print `url: /path?param=1` when you connect to `ws://myserver.com/path?param=1`.

Comment: how to get passed parameter in the .jsp page?

Comment: just a note: you can then [parse the url](http://www.codingdefined.com/2014/11/how-to-parse-urls-in-nodejs.html) using [`url.parse()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parsing)

Comment: update: upgradeReq property was removed.

see https://github.com/websockets/ws/pull/1099

Comment: to use with latest ws. the connection callback now has another argument - which is req. 
[code]
wss.on("connection", (ws, req) => {
  console.log(`Conn Url ${req.url}`);
});
[/code]

Answer (score 39):

To use with latest ws, the connection callback now has another argument - which is req.

```
wss.on("connection", (ws, req) => {
   console.log(`Conn Url ${req.url}`);
});
```