# Node.js, Websocket server-side client data

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server, steam-web-api

First of all, I hope that you understand what I need.
Here is my current server side script:

```
var server = require('websocket').server, http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var socket = new server({
    httpServer: http.createServer().listen(8080)
});



var sql = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : ''
});

sql.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('[MySQL] Error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log('[MySQL] Connected as id ' + sql.threadId);
});

socket.on('request', function(request) {
    var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        connection.sendUTF(message);
    });

    connection.on('close', function(connection) {
        console.log('connection closed');
    });
});
```

Clients connect to websocket using an unique query:

```
var WS = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/steamid="+steamid);
```

Now to what I need.
In the server side, I need to get client's **steamid** and save it so I can use it later in the server. For example, I need to fetch the **steamid of a 10th client**. I believe this has to be done with arrays, but I'm kinda green in those things.

Thanks in advance,
Nedas

Comment: `ws://localhost:8080/steamid=steamid` does not look like a valid url. It should look like that i guess: `ws://localhost:8080/?steamid=steamid`? Is your question how to access that query parameter? Then this question could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301269/can-websocket-addresses-carry-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect the request object and [parse](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) the contents of the connection URL ([`request.resource`](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/master/lib/WebSocketRequest.js#L94), [`request.httpRequest.url`](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/master/lib/WebSocketRequest.js#L93)) or [`request.resourceURL`](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/master/lib/WebSocketRequest.js#L115) directly to retrieve the `steamid` query parameter value.

As for the steamid of the nth client:

You can access all connections of the websocket server like this:

```
server.connections[10]
```

Then proceed as mentioned above; retrieve and parse connection url to find the `steamid` query parameter.