# How to pass parameter with path in websocket server in node js

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have setup below socket with the path but i couldn't pass the parameter with the path.
So, can anyone provide any solution that how can i pass it

```
const webSocketServer = require('ws');

class WebSocket {
    constructor (server) {
        this.server = server;
        this.socket = new webSocketServer.Server({ server, path: "/ws" });
        //this.socket = new webSocketServer.Server({ server, path: "/ws/:id" });
        // I want like this the commented code above want to pass id after the /ws
        this.connect();
    }
```

```
this.socket = new webSocketServer.Server({ server, path: "/ws/:id" });
```

I have tried like this but it didn't work.
Also there is nothing in its documentation.
https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md

Comment: Hi, Did you read this ? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301269/can-websocket-addresses-carry-parameters

You can try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50652367/4885936

Comment: Hi I have checked that but it is not relevant as when i add path parameter on websocket initialization then the path is fixed and we can't pass anything else expect that defined path